# How to set default workspace when developing Launcher3

Tags: android-launcher

guys, I got a question when developing Launcher3 here： https://github.com/jp1017/Launcher3

I what to change the `default work_space` of the Launcher3, bu it doesn't work.

I modify the file `default_workspace_4x4.xml`，it doesn't work for me.

and I get a msg, the Id of `default_workspace_4x4.xml` doesn't equal mProfile.defaultLayoutId, neither nor `default_workspace_5x5.xm` and `default_workspace_5x6.xml`

so, what should i do.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Delete all other xml files except `default_workspace_4x4.xml`.

Comment: I have just default_workspace.xml & update_workspace.xml & default_workspace_no_all_apps.xml. Just like https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/res/xml/

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for what?! I just want to say your solution doesn't work for me :D .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all other default xml files except `default_workspace_4x4.xml`

just like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/res/xml/